# How to draw this circuit with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I am a total newbie to circuitikz. I want to draw these two circuits

[image]

[image]

I want to know how to do this. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Posting a picture and asking users to reproduce it is not really the way to go in this site. As you have indeed tagged this question as `circuitikz`-related, you could start by reading the documentation of the package and looking at similar questions already posted on this site. _Then_, if you find trouble, please ask a specific question about what it is that's hindering you.

Comment: yes i am having trouble making it. that is why I asked it here.

Comment: All of this is shown in the manual. Please show some effort. We are volunteers trying to help, not to offer unpaid work. Even the easiest lines of code such as the documentclass are missing here and give us more stuff to type. Please extract the very problem you encounter (after trying some minutes) and put it in your post! Thanks.

Comment: There are 8 answers in the duplicate link, but I failed to see any operational amplifiers or diodes were drawn there via `circuitikz`. How can a newbie find clues there?

Comment: Thanks for this. Thanks also fro understanding the problems of newbies. how do I scale this circuit? Just adding the command \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5] in the beginning does not scale it properly –

Answer (score 8):

The basic syntax is

```
\documentclass[standalone] % or article and other classes.
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (x1,y1) to[<circuit element like, R,L,C>, i=<value>,v=<value>,l=<label>,color=<color>]
      (x2,y2) to[same as above]
      (x3,y3) to[same as above]
      ...
      (xn,yn);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Please read the manual for more detail [Circuitikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) or tutorials [One of many tutorial](http://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/advanced/lesson-12/)

[image]

Here is the code to achieve the circuit above

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}  
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (2,2.5) node[op amp] (opamp1) {$A_1$}
(0.8,0) node [ground] {} to [sV] (0.8,1) |- (opamp1.+)
(opamp1.-) -- + (0,1) -| (opamp1.out);
\draw (6,2) node[op amp] (opamp2) {$A_2$}
(opamp1.out) to [R=$10K$]  (opamp2.-) 
(4.8,1) node [ground] {}to [short] (opamp2.+)
(opamp2.-) -- +(0,1.5) to[R,l=$1M$] +(2.3,1.5) -|
(opamp2.out) to [short,-o] (8, 2)node[right]{$V_o$};
\end{circuitikz}\\
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,1) to[battery1,l=$10V$] (0,4) to[R=$1K$,i=$I$] (3,4) to[D] (3,1)-- (0,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Thanks also fro understanding the problems of newbies. how do I scale this circuit? Just adding the command \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5] in the beginning does not scale it properly

Comment: Add [...] to the right of `circuitikz` environment as such `\begin{circuitikz}[transform shape, scale=0.5]`

Comment: Thanks again. There is still another point. I would like to put both r and 10K in the 1st circuit togther. Else I would like to put r=10K in place of 10K. This seems difficult to do. How can we do it?

Comment: Change `R=$10K$` into `R,l=${r=10K}$`.

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Thanks again. Upvoted.

Comment: One problem is that `opamp1.out` and `opamp2.-` are not completely leveled (0.5 vertical distance is only approximative).  This can be achieved by a slight modification, which I can do it if there is interest.